# I was running my code after several successful output I a have this error now

Tags: python, json, api

I was running my code after several successful output I a have this error now.

> raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>
> JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Could you please help me?

```
payload={"name":"new data"}
requestpost=requests.get('https://...free.beeceptor.com/favicon.ico',json=payload)
current_t0 = requestpost.json()
```

Comment: Can you directly run `json.dumps(payload)`? Which OS is this?

Comment: I need to send a request to url to get a JSON file.

Comment: The JSON you're getting is invalid.

Comment: as stated, it's not a valid json. Unless you provide the full code for any to re-produce the error, noone will be able to help you beyond this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should use `data=` parameter instead of `json=` in a `GET` request.

Comment: again the same error: requestpost=requests.get('https://pisces.free.beeceptor.com/favicon.ico',data=payload)
current_t0 = requestpost.json()